# Vaadin 24 , unable to get combox custom Value

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin24

I started using Vaadin 24. I am using combobox and set allowcustomvalue true. Now I want to read whatever I type on combobox on button click, I am unable to do that. Could someone please help

I tried below but not success

comboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
String customValue = event.getValue();

});